# Error when pasting Excel's formulas

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwings

I' have recently started using xlwings to replace my old VBA codes. Everything seems to work ok except for the error that appears when I try to paste a formula.

To simplify, my code is this

```
F= 'Excel Formula'
range('A given cell').formula = F
```

The error that I get is

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurri\xf3 una excepci\xf3n.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Any idea for solving this?
Thanks

Comment: Any formula, on any range, on any file? If not, can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the equal sign in the formula. Here's a simple example:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw
>>> wb = xw.Book()
>>> wb.sheets[0].range('A1').formula = '=A1+A2'
```

Comment: After adding the equal sign, the add function works well.However, my problem is with the vlookup (or BUSCARV in spanish).